# where used fields in BOM

Tags: sap-erp

I have a part list and i have a field "where used" to set the location of this component in BOMs (it can have multiple locations): this is a field with multiple input values (each value is a BOM name).

**partName___description________         whereUsed**

432AB23_______         part1________            X234 - X211 - X320

632AC31_______         part2_______________                   X234

764CD21_______         part3____________                X320 - X211

I would have a query where I can select BOM name and retrieve all the associated components.
I have no idea how to do and every advice are appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a help site about programming questions. If you ask a question about the database model of SAP ERP concerning Bill Of Material (BOM), you should better ask your question in [SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com) forums.

Comment: you don't know how to find workcenter for a BOM?

Comment: I'm trying  to build myself a table in mysql  with bom explosion, normalizing the field " where used". I don't use SAP or similar.

Answer (score 0):

as this was posted with tag sap-erp, in ABAP it would be (if you´re searching for e.g. X234):

`SELECT * FROM your_table INTO TABLE internal_table WHERE whereUsed LIKE '%X234%'`.

second option would be to use a range table for whereUsed with option = 'CP'.